# My jquery sortable is not sorting

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a simple scroll that I want to enforce a sortable in just to make it fun. Yet 
I can't see why it's not sorting like it should.

```
$('.sorting').sortable({cursor:'pointer',
    tolerance:'pointer', scroll: false, revert: true});
```

I have a visual [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/230/). In addition, I know I'm not the best in making things look good i.e Css, but I'm trying so if there is something I am not doing correctly or that looks off I'll be be very open and appreciative to the tip(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a jquery selector issue check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/235/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {



     $('.sorting').sortable({cursor:'pointer',
    tolerance:'pointer', scroll: false, revert: true});

});
```

css

```
   #movelist{
   /* float : left;*/
    width: 322px;
    height: 205px;
}

.mousescroll{
  overflow: hidden;  

}
.mousescroll:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sort li{
border: solid 1px #48B1D9; 
list-style:none;
width:200px;
position:relative;
left:100px;
}

​
```